# Format last tick as 24:00 instead of 00:00

Tags: d3.js

Using d3 range I am able to create ticks for every three hours:

[image]

However, the last time indication is marked as 00:00 instead of 24:00. What part should change to have it displaying 24:00 instead of 00:00?

```
import { format } from 'https://esm.run/date-fns';

const startDate = new Date("2021-03-14T23:00:00.000Z");
const endDate = new Date("2021-03-15T23:00:00.000Z");
const endDateInclusive = d3.timeMinute.offset(endDate, 1); // solution: add 1 minute for upper boundary of range
const dayInThreeHourPeriods = d3.timeHour.every(3).range(startDate, endDateInclusive);

const d3Root = document.getElementById('d3-root');
const svg = d3.select(d3Root).append('svg')
  .attr('width', 800)
  .attr('height', 80)

const xScale = d3
  .scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(dayInThreeHourPeriods))
  .range([0, 700]);

const xAxis = d3
  .axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%H:%M'))
  .tickValues(dayInThreeHourPeriods)
  .tickSize(0)
  .tickPadding(10);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x-axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(30,20)' )
  .call(xAxis);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace **d3.timeFormat** in **tickFormat** with a custom formatter:

```
const d3TimeFormat = d3.timeFormat('%H:%M');  
const formatTime = (value, index) => {
  const firstValue = index === 0;
  return value.getHours() === 0 && !firstValue ? '24:00' : d3TimeFormat(value)
};
...
const xAxis = d3
  .axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickFormat(formatTime)
  ...
```

Comment: Great! Used the second argument `(value, index) ...` to check if it's not the first value, that way it skips that one and the timeline goes from 00:00 to 24:00.